# Set Tag on AWS::EC2::Instances BlockStorage of root Volume via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, tags, config, aws-cloudformation

We want to **tag every resource of a cloudformation stack** with a specific tag (for billing and financial reasons). This includes the **main storage used on the main partition mounted under (/dev/sda1).**

This is what we have:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: The Name
Parameters:
  InstanceType:
    Description: EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t3.small
    AllowedValues:
    - t3.nano
    - ...
  InstanceName:
    Description: Name Tag
    Type: String
Resources:
  TheECCInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      KeyName: jenkins
      ImageId: !FindInMap [RegionMap, !Ref 'AWS::Region', AMI]
      InstanceType:
        Ref: InstanceType
      SubnetId: subnet-0e9c7d7c2711aaf9e
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: "/dev/sda1"
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize:
              Ref: EBSBlockSize
            VolumeType: gp2
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value:
          Ref: InstanceName
      - Key: Type
        Value: TheType

Mappings:
  RegionMap:
    'ap-northeast-3':
      NAME: ap-northeast-3b
      AMI: 'ami-05e896b95030bd37c'
    'sa-east-1':
      NAME: sa-east-1b
      AMI: 'ami-03c6239555bb12112'
    'eu-west-1':
      NAME: eu-west-1b
      AMI: 'ami-00035f41c82244dab'
    ...

Outputs:
  ...
```

I **would not mind using something like that**:

```
  RootVolume:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Volume      // Or Something in that direction (EFS / EBS / whatever)
    Properties:
      Size:
        Ref: EBSBlockSize
      VolumeType: gp2
      AvailabilityZone: !FindInMap [RegionMap, !Ref 'AWS::Region', NAME]
      Tags:
        - Key: Type
          Value: TheType
```

**and mounting it**. It just seems impossible, to get it attached as the main partition. Either as AWS::EC2::Volume, AWS::EFS, etc. Any help here would be appreciated. We currently create the instance and then tag after stack creation. But that seems somewhat fragile and there should be an easier way doing this....

Comment: The code above is simplified and modified for readability.

Comment: AFAIK You can use BlockDeviceMappings to do this. You do need to define the EBS separately though.

Comment: Thx @DroidX86. But the problem is not the device in general. It is the root device. I can spawn ephemerals, but "/dev/sda1" seems to be a an issue...

Comment: Why is that? Any error?

Comment: Different errors. I will try to update the question after I collected them.

Comment: @DroidX86 found that this answers it pretty well: https://serverfault.com/questions/876942/create-new-ec2-instance-with-existing-ebs-volume-as-root-device-using-cloudforma

Comment: Will update the question and mark it as duplicate tomorrow. Short: It is not possible to spawn the root volume as a separate EBS Volume, as AMI initialization will not allow it...

Comment: You might want to check whether tags applied to an Amazon EC2 propagate to the EBS volumes. This is an option in the management console, but might be ON by default when launching through CloudFormation. The `RunInstances` documentation says "The specified tags are applied to all instances or volumes that are created during launch."

Comment: One would think so. But they dont. Even tags applied to the "stack" do not propagate to the root volume.

Comment: Workaround with aws-cli and EC2 userdata (Linux OS only)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891037/retrieve-correct-amazon-attached-ebs-device-from-instance-metadata-endpoint/55158550#55158550

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Not possible with cloud formation

It turns out, this is not possible with aws cloudformation. 
This question hinted me to this answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/876942/create-new-ec2-instance-with-existing-ebs-volume-as-root-device-using-cloudforma

#### Solution with terraform

It is pretty simple with "terraform":

```
resource "aws_instance" "someName" {
  ami           = "ami-***********"
  instance_type = "t2.*******"
  tags          = {
    Type = "InstanceTag"
  }
  volume_tags   = {
    Type = "VolumeTag"
  }
}
```

#### Our solution (Jenkins and shell script)

We use cloudformation to spawn our CI-Instances via jenkins. Moving to terraform would have resulted in more work then we were willing to take. We needed the tags for cost calculation. So when realizing that cloudformation was no option, we used the cli to tag the instances after they were created.

Obviously, the awscli has to be installed. The credentials come via environment variables.

Here is the script we used:

```sh
sleep 1m
EC2_VOLUMES=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region "${INSTANCE_REGION}" --filter "Name=tag-key,Values=Type" "Name=tag-value,Values=Jenkins" --filter "Name=tag-key,Values=Name" "Name=tag-value,Values=BackendJenkins${BUILD_NUMBER}" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*].Ebs.[VolumeId]" --output text)

echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY | base64 -i > foo.txt

while read -r RESOURCE; do
    # We set the name and the type tag
    aws ec2 create-tags --resources "$RESOURCE" --region "${INSTANCE_REGION}" --tags "Key=Type,Value=TheTagValue"
    aws ec2 create-tags --resources "$RESOURCE" --region "${INSTANCE_REGION}" --tags "Key=Name,Value=TheInstanceName${BUILD_NUMBER}"
done <<< "$EC2_VOLUMES"
```

Thx for all the hints about spawning EC2::Volumes and Tag Propagation.

Comment: Actually the part about terraform is not correct. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3531

Comment: I would also suggest a better approach that the script will only tag the EBS volumes based on the tags that the instance has, so the management of the tags is still under CloudFormation for traceability, and the automation only tag the EBS volumes from the instance tags already deployed (this is what we're doing)

Comment: @Dvir669 The Issue you mention was closed and resolved via: 
- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/14007
It is indeed working for us as far as I can tell. Sorry if this was somehow misleading for you.

Comment: @Dvir669 thx for the second hint. We currently use jenkins and can - as such - separate builds by build number. This means instances are generated with a unique name and a commit-sha, so we are pretty shure what was build and will be tagged.

I proposed the solution as such is just a simplified version of what we do. Still it would be nice to have the ability being built into Cloudformation.
Thx for your ideas though.